# Reading PROGMEM results in an incorrect hex value

Tags: avr, progmem

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid here, but the code below is supposed to write the test hex values to a I2C EEPROM, however when I attempt to read the EEPROM it has the wrong values.  Directly calling something like Wire.write(0xab) will write the 0xab as expected, so I know the EEPROM is being written to properly, just something seems to be getting lost in translation when writing test[counter++]
.

```
#include <Wire.h>

const byte test[] PROGMEM = {
  0x80, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x80, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x80, 0x7f, 0x80, 0x7f, 0x80, 0x80,
  0x7f, 0x7f, 0x81, 0x7f, 0x7e, 0x81, 0x80, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x80, 0x7e,
  0x7e, 0x81, 0x7e, 0x7c, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7d, 0x7c, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x80, 0x7e
};

unsigned int test_len = 36;

#define EEPROM_ADR 0x50

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin();

  int counter = 0;

  Wire.beginTransmission(EEPROM_ADR);

  Wire.write((int)(0x0 >> 8)); //msb
  Wire.write((int)(0x0 & 0xFF)); //lsb

  while (counter < test_len)
  {
    Wire.write(test[counter++]); //using page buffering to write the entire array
  }

  Wire.endTransmission();
}
```

The results look something like: 0x00 0x00 0x08 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 etc..

Comment: remove PROGMEM to test. you don't use the pgm_read function to read PROGMEM

Comment: what is the purpose of the first two `Wire.write`  commands?  .... i think that they both write a zero ... is something missing from those two lines?

Comment: Juraj, you're right, but in my real code the array is quite large so it needs to be in PROGMEM, is there something I'm missing about that memory location?

Comment: That was it, it works.

Comment: you learned how to troubleshoot. next time create a minimal sketch. now please delete the question.

Comment: To obtain the size of your array you can use `sizeof test / sizeof test[0]`. This works with any data type of an array's elements.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to either remove PROGMEM from the array or use pgm_read_byte to read the array.